# Change jQuery Mobile transition when using trigger('click')

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to have a navigation menu that reflects page changes based on clicks and swipes. To perform this I've had to trigger a click when I swipe. Problem is, when I do this, I can no longer use:

```
$.mobile.changePage(prevpage, { transition : 'realslide', reverse : true });
```

With the property `reverse:true` being the important part. 'swipeleft' can have a regular transition but 'swiperight' needs a reverse transition and I can't do this in the HTML with `data-transition="reverse"` because it's dependant on the swipe direction.

Currently this is what my code looks like (provided by user [Jasper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/752738/jasper?tab=summary)). I'm not sure where I can tie in the reverse transition in.

```
$(function(){
    var $nav   = $('#nav').children().children(),
        totNav = $nav.length;

    $(document).on('swipeleft', '.ui-page', function() {

        var next = ($nav.filter('.active').index() + 1);

        if (next === totNav)
            return;

        $nav.eq(next).children().trigger('click');

    }).on('swiperight', '.ui-page', function() {

        var prev = ($nav.filter('.active').index() - 1);

        if (prev === -1)
            return;

        $nav.eq(prev).children().trigger('click');

    }).on('click', '#nav a', function(e) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

This question is an extension of this: [Update menu in jQuery Mobile based on swipe event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687584/update-menu-in-jquery-mobile-based-on-swipe-event)

**EDIT:**
Thanks everyone for your help! Here is my final solution:

```
    <script>
    $(function(){

        var $nav    = $('#nav').children().children(),
            totNav  = $nav.length;

        $(document).on('swipeleft', '.ui-page', function() {

            var next = ($nav.filter('.active').index() + 1);
            var $elem = $nav.eq(next).children();

            if (next === totNav)
                return;

            $.mobile.changePage.defaults.reverse = false;

            $elem.trigger('click');

        }).on('swiperight', '.ui-page', function() {

            var prev = ($nav.filter('.active').index() - 1);
            var $elem = $nav.eq(prev).children();

            if (prev === -1)
                return;

            $.mobile.changePage.defaults.reverse = true;

            $elem.trigger('click');

        }).on('click', '#nav a', function(e) {

            var prev = $nav.filter('.active').index();

            $(this).parent().addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");

            var now = $nav.filter('.active').index();

            if (prev > now)
                $.mobile.changePage.defaults.reverse = true;
            else
                $.mobile.changePage.defaults.reverse = false;

        });

    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okey, this solution might be a bit hackish, but it works.

Before you trigger the event you can set the default page transition to be reversed, then after the trigger set it to the default value. I have not tried it, but I think it might be achieved like this:

```
$(function(){
    var $nav   = $('#nav').children().children(),
        totNav = $nav.length;

    $(document).on('swipeleft', '.ui-page', function() {

        var next = ($nav.filter('.active').index() + 1);
    $.mobile.changePage.defaults.reverse = true; // Reverse transition
        $nav.eq(next).children().trigger('click');
    $.mobile.changePage.defaults.reverse = false; // Dont reverse


    }).on('swiperight', '.ui-page', function() {

        var prev = ($nav.filter('.active').index() - 1);
        $nav.eq(prev).children().trigger('click');

    }).on('click', '#nav a', function(e) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't believe that worked. The documentation said that those sort of defaults had to be set before jquery mobile was loaded using `$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){});`, so I didn't think they couldn't be changed on the fly.